# Softkeyboard blocking EditText

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-edittext

I'm having the following problem:

I have an activity which enables a user to post comments on some article. When the user taps the `EditText` field where the comment can be posted, the `softkeyboard` ends up blocking the text field such that the user can't see what is being typed. How can I make sure that the `EditText` field is always, at least partly, visible?

Comment: If your application is in the full screen, remove the full screen code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the contents of your activity to a scrollable layout and when the EditText view gets focus manually scroll the ScrollView.

Comment: A ScrollView containing an EditText will automatically scroll so the EditText widget is visible when the soft keyboard is launched.

Answer (score 1):

Make your layout scrollable by using scrollview so that the Edittext will scroll to up and placed above the softkeyboard and you can view the EditText.