# EditText blocked by keyboard when it is clicked

Tags: android, android-layout

The question title may be misleading, but I have what I think is a common issue for Android newbies: I have an activity with a `LinearLayout`, and I have an `EditText` at the bottom of the screen. When I click on it, the keyboard appears over the `EditText`, hiding it while typing. Is there a way to achieve what most user expect, that is the activity gets scrolled down until the `EditText` becomes visible again?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411267/softkeyboard-blocking-edittext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ScrollView` as top view. and define the `RelativeLayout` in that.

Define like as

```
<Scrollview.......>
   <RelativeLayout .....>
         //other view.
   </RelativeLayout >
</Scrollview>
```

Comment: @shridutt kothari I gave the example how he can apply this in his problem..that

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `ScrollView` to achieve this.

Comment: Update: is the AVD *this* terrible? I restarted the application and now it behaves exactly as it should.

Comment: @whatyouhide the AVDs are terrible in general ;)

Answer (score 1):

Add the contents of your `LinearLayout` to a `Scrollview` and when the `EditText` view gets focused, `manually scroll` the `ScrollView`.
Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"` to your activity in manifest?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this if adjustResize still fails to fully show the view you desire.  Whatever view your concerned about make a onTouchListener and then do this:

```
    setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()  {



        Runnable shifter=new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                try {
                    int[] loc = new int[2];                 
                    //get the location of someview which gets stored in loc array
                    findViewById(R.id.someview).getLocationInWindow(loc);
                    //shift so user can see someview
                    myscrollView.scrollTo(loc[0], loc[1]);   
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }   
            }}
        };

        Rect scrollBounds = new Rect();
        View divider=findViewById(R.id.someview);
        myscollView.getHitRect(scrollBounds);
        if (!divider.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds))  {
            // the divider view is NOT  within the visible scroll window thus we need to scroll a bit.
            myscollView.postDelayed(shifter, 500);
        }



    });
```

//essentially we make a runnable that scrolls to a new location of some view that you WANT visible on the screen.  you execute that runnable only if its not within the scrollviews bounds (its not on the screen).  This way it shifts the scrollview to the referenced view (in my case 'someview' which was a line divider).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` to your targetted activity at manifest.